# Wait for XCTestExpectation before starting next unit test in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xctestexpectation

I have a number of asynchronous unit tests which work correctly on their own using expectations.  However when I run all the tests in the suit, they do not wait for each other to complete - the asynchronous callbacks are still pending when the next tests start running.  What I want is for each test to wait for the expectations in the previous test before running.  These tests use a shared database, so having them overlap leads to annoying additional complexity, and failing tests when run as a suite.

```
- (void)testSignIn {
// This is an example of a functional test case.
// Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.

XCTestExpectation *expectation =
[self expectationWithDescription:@"Expectations"];

[_userManager signInWithUsername:kUserEmail andPassword:kUserPassword
                         success:^{
                             XCTAssertNotNil([_userManager getCurrentUser]);

                             XCTAssertNotNil([_userManager getCurrentUser].plan);
                             XCTAssertTrue([_userManager getCurrentUser].plan.liveStream == TRUE);

                             [expectation fulfill];

                         } failure:^(EDApiError *apiError) {
                             XCTAssertTrue(FALSE); // Should not fail
                             [expectation fulfill];

                         }];

[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5.0 handler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Timeout Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

}

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, one test should fail/succeed before beginning the next one, which either way must fulfill the expectation. The only thing I can think of is that the `testSignIn` is called from 2 places of a single test. 1. So please make sure you're not running it twice from a single test. 2. Additionally 5 seconds timeout is a bit too little. I would recommend making it at least 30 seconds.

Comment: Looks like the expectations need to have different description strings.  I had all mine set to the same string, which appears to have caused the behavior I was seeing.

Comment: (removed my previous comment) I'm trying to make sense of that. I mean still no 2 tests are running at the same time. So even though this works, I'm guessing this isn't the root cause...

Comment: I didn't read it all myself yet, but see [XCTestExpectation Gotchas](https://jeremywsherman.com/blog/2016/03/19/xctestexpectation-gotchas/#summary-dodged)

Answer (score 0):

Use [XCTWaiter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctwaiter) or [waitForExpectations(timeout:handler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1500748-waitforexpectations) to stall the completion of each test until the expectations have been fulfilled.

This blog post explains some of the more complex pitfalls you might come across when writing asynchronous tests and how to prevent them: https://jeremywsherman.com/blog/2016/03/19/xctestexpectation-gotchas/

Comment: See my updated question above.  I am using waitForExpectation, but the tests don't appear to stall completion, they just continue on to the next test and then complete in their own time (with either success or fail) so long as they complete in under the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I've found you need to fulfil expectations on the main thread - important if your async completion block is maybe running on another thread. I've also found that the problem can be triggered by a faulty test that ran earlier, so it isn't always caused by the test the failure manifests in.

Also, watch if you're spawning lots of async blocks (I do this for crazy thread safety tests, or tests checking exclusive access to a resource is working as expected, and in the order expected). Once you fulfil the expectation, the testing moves on to the next test, but if you've fired off a lot of async blocks after that point, they're maybe still running.